# Docker specifying user and group as exec command options

Tags: docker, user-permissions

I need to execute some commands from inside a [php/php-7.1](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/0bb4068bd639ba98631bc2999e0d20cae583ec00/7.1/jessie/fpm/Dockerfile) container as a special (standard) user and group aka «*www-data:www-data*» used by php-fpm daemon.

*www-data* exists as both a user and a group on the host machine and entries exist in :

- */etc/passwd* `www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/usr/sbin/nologin`
- */etc/group* `www-data:x:33:`

Anyway, while the container is running, I firstly get the *www-data* uid and gid , as follows:

```
// con_php is the running container's name
echo $(docker exec -it con_php bash -c 'echo "$(id -u www-data)"''":"''"$(id -g www-data)"')
// outputs 33:33, great !
```

Then I use this (as a command line substitution) to feed the *--user* option supplied to the actual command I need to run inside the container. I now have:

```
docker exec \
    --user $(docker exec -it con_php bash -c 'echo "$(id -u www-data)"''":"''"$(id -g www-data)"') \
    con_php \
    bash -c 'cd /var/www/project ; touch test.txt'
```

**Unfortunately**, when executed, Docker complains and outputs an error:

> : no matching entries in group file

---

The following approach (a bash script with a temporary variable) leads to the same issue:

```
#! /bin/bash

usr=$(docker exec -it con_php bash -c 'echo "$(id -u www-data)"''":"''"$(id -g www-data)"')
echo "» $usr"
docker exec --user $usr con_php bash -c 'cd /var/www/project ; touch test.txt'
```

> » 33:33
>     : no matching entries in group file

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrieving data from within a docker container sometimes comes in handy.
Beware if you use `echo` to gather output as a word (or a single line). Make sure to use `-n` option which prevent a trailing newline character to be prepended.

```
$ docker exec -it my_container bash -c 'echo -n "$(…)"'
```

Otherwise, you may encounter failure/misbehavior when consuming the output.
Like as an argument in a Bash process command.